# tmux status bar sub section layout

Tags: layout, position, statusbar, tmux

I got my current tmux status bar like this:

```
[[left:a+b+c]              [status-justify:m]                       [right:h]]
```

now the problem is that session c is has a dynamic information for current directory, so the length changes when pane changes. It is so annoy that the status-justify part m's position changes when switching window/pane.

the section c is so tied to a and b which i really don't want to put together with h to avoid the issue, so my question is:

is there a way that I can put m as sub section after a+b and followed with c, like this:

```
[[left:a+b+m+c]                                   [right:h]]
```

since the other ares are all quite stable in terms of size, so I achieve the goal.

yes, i understand i can change status-justify to centre, however it will follow the full section of left part, like this:

```
[[left:a+b+c]+m                                 [right:h]]
```

which is not what I want

Any idea?